# C# Getting ip address from a connected wifi adapter on UWP

Tags: uwp

After spending lot of time on the web (nearly 2 days) I've discovered from Microsoft that the class systen.net.IpAddress does not works yet on UWP (awaiting from them an expected date for it).

What I'm looking for is to get the ipaddress of the connected wifi adapter. This looks like simple but I'm running in an infernal loop and wish you can help me.

1 Names space used :

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation; 
using Windows.Devices.WiFi; 
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity; 
using Windows.Security.Credentials; 
using System.Linq; 
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
```

2 - Variables at top (not all are used yet)

```
//For wifi adapter choosen by the user
private WiFiAdapter wifiSelectedAdapter;
//For wifi network to connect to choosen by the user
private WiFiAvailableNetwork wifiSelectedNetwork;
//For the connection profile
private ConnectionProfile connectionProfile;
private DeviceInformationCollection deviceInfoCollection;
private IPInformation ipInformation;
private string _string;
private string cnxProfile;
private object _object;
```

3 Finding available adapter

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Request wifi access from the device
    var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
    if (access != WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
    {
        tblDebug.Text = "Access denied";
    }
    else
    {
        DataContext = this;
        // Find all wifi adapters on the equipment
        deviceInfoCollection = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
        if (deviceInfoCollection.Count < 1)
        {
            tblDebug.Text = "No WiFi Adapters detected on you device.";
        }
        else
        {
            List<object> ls = new List<object>();
            var test = 0;
            foreach (var item in deviceInfoCollection)
            {
                ls.Add(item.Name);
                test = test + 1;
            }
            ListViewResult.ItemsSource = ls;
            tblDebug.Text = "Please select the wifi adapter to scan with and click scan button";
            btScan.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

4 - selecting adapter and start scan

```
private void ListViewResult_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    _string = e.ClickedItem as string;
    tblDebug.Text = "";
}
private async void btScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_string == null)
    {
        tblDebug.Text = "Please select an adapter before scanning wifi network";
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var selecteditem in deviceInfoCollection)
        {
            if (selecteditem.Name == _string)
            {
                var _id = selecteditem.Id;
                try
                {
                    //var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
                    wifiSelectedAdapter = await WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync(_id);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        //Clear ListView previous adapters list
        ListViewResult.ItemsSource = null;
        tblDebug.Text = "";
        //Scan wifi available network
        await wifiSelectedAdapter.ScanAsync();

        //Populate ListView with available wifi network
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        var test = 0;
        foreach (var network in wifiSelectedAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks)
        {
            ls.Add(network.Ssid);
            test = test + 1;
        }
        ListViewResult.ItemsSource = ls;

        if (test <= 0)
        {
            tblDebug.Text = "No wifi network found.";
        }
        else
        {
            tblDebug.Text = "Select the network in the list, you want to connect to and click Connect button.";
            btConnect.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            tblWifiNetwork.Text = "We found the following network(s) :";
        }
    }
}
```

5 Selecting a network and connect

```
private async void btConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var selecteditem in wifiSelectedAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks)
    {
        if (selecteditem.Ssid == _string)
        {
            wifiSelectedNetwork = selecteditem;
        }
    }

    //Empty the ListViewResult
    ListViewResult.ItemsSource = null;

    //Create the reconnection Kind to be passed for the connection
    WiFiReconnectionKind reconnectionKind = WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic;

    // Create the result to catch the connection result
    WiFiConnectionResult result;

    if (wifiSelectedNetwork.SecuritySettings.NetworkAuthenticationType == NetworkAuthenticationType.Open80211 &&
wifiSelectedNetwork.SecuritySettings.NetworkEncryptionType == NetworkEncryptionType.None)
    {
        tblWifiNetwork.Text = "";
        result = await wifiSelectedAdapter.ConnectAsync(wifiSelectedNetwork, reconnectionKind);
        connectionProfile = await wifiSelectedAdapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync();
        cnxProfile = connectionProfile.ProfileName;


        btDisconnect.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        if (result.ConnectionStatus == WiFiConnectionStatus.Success)
        {
            tblDebug.Text = "You are connected to " + cnxProfile + " with ip ";// + ttt.ToString();
            btDisconnect.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btIpaddress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            tblDebug.Text = "Sorry but we can't connect you to the selected network.";
            wifiSelectedAdapter.Disconnect();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        gridSecKey.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        tblDebug.Text = "The network you are trying to connect to is secured, please enter the security key.";

        // Only the password portion of the credential need to be supplied
        var credential = new PasswordCredential();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwNetworkKey.Password))
        {
            credential.Password = pwNetworkKey.Password;
            result = await wifiSelectedAdapter.ConnectAsync(wifiSelectedNetwork, reconnectionKind, credential);
        }
        else
        {
            tblDebug.Text = "Please enter the security key before connecting.";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

At this stage I get connected to the desired wifinetwork.

6 Here is where I'm stuck

```
private async void btIpaddress_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _networkAdapterId = wifiSelectedAdapter.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId;
    var _connectedProfile = await wifiSelectedAdapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync();
    var _profileName = _connectedProfile.ProfileName;
    var cnxProfile = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles().ToList();
    List<object> _list = new List<object>();
    foreach (var item in cnxProfile)
    {
        if (_profileName == item.ProfileName)
        {
            List<string> ipAddress = new List<string>();
            var Hosts = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
            foreach (var Host in Hosts)
            {
                var tt = Host.DisplayName;
                {
                    string IP = Host.DisplayName;
                    ipAddress.Add(IP);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- First I'm getting the id of the adapter I'm connected with "_networkAdapterId"
- Then I get the profile I'm connected with "_connectedProfile"
- Then I get the connected profile name "_profileName"
- Then I get the list of profile from NetworkInformation "cnxProfile"

With the function `NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();` I'm getting all the hostnames actually connected on my equipment.

The question : How to link my `_networkAdapterId` with the relevant hostname from the function `NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()` ?

[image: GetHostNames() value]

[image: Host.Displayname value]

In the second picture, below IPInformation/NetworkAdapter we can find the NetworkAdapterID.

In other words, from this NetworkAdapterID, how can I retrieve it's IP address on UWP ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I came to as solution which looks like not so bad :)

```
'var _networkAdapterId = wifiSelectedAdapter.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId;
 var connectedProfile = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles().ToList();
 foreach (var item in connectedProfile)
 {
    if (_networkAdapterId == item.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId)
    {
        var hostname = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
                           .SingleOrDefault(
                                hn =>
                                hn.IPInformation != null && hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter != null
                                && hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId
                                == _networkAdapterId);
        if (hostname != null)
        {
           // the ip address
           _connectedIpAddress = hostname.CanonicalName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the goal is to retrieve the remote ipaddress, the one which has given me my ip (in other words my gateway from the ip point of view) still knowing that ICMP is not working for UWP project :) Any ideas are welcome :).